# ASPxGridView java alternative?

Tags: java, .net, ajax, datagrid, aspxgridview

I really like ASPxGridView, but I can't use .NET to develop my applications. I wonder if there is a Java or more generic alternative to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hai rsilva,

Have a look at [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/examples/).... Really a worth a try...